# How to update taggable using rtconner/laravel-tagging in laravel Error "Call to a member function tag() on int"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, tags, laravel-8

how to make update data taggable using rtconner/laravel-tagging in laravel, I have been try on this code in my project, this is the code for repository

```
    public function updateNews($id, $data)
    {
        $tags = explode(',', $data['tags']);
        unset($data['tags']);
        $model = $this->model->where('id', $id)->update($data);
        $model->tag($tags);
        return $model;
    }
```

and this is the code for the controller

```
    public function update(NewsUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $this->newsService->getById($id);
        $validated = $request->validated();
        if (isset($request->thumbnail)) {
            $path = public_path() . '/uploads/';
            if ($data->thumbnail != '' && $data->thumbnail != null) {
                $file_old = $path . $data->thumbnail;
                unlink($file_old);
            }
            $filenew = $validated['thumbnail'];
            $update_file = rand() . $filenew->getClientOriginalName();
            $filenew->move(public_path('uploads'), $update_file);
            $validated['thumbnail'] = $update_file;
        }
        $userId = $this->newsService->update($id, $validated);
        Alert::success(' Berhasil Ubah Data ', ' Silahkan Periksa Kembali');
        return redirect()->route('news.index');
    }
```

and this is for the form requests

```
class NewsUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:news,title,' . $this->route('news'),
            'content' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'thumbnail' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required'    => 'Title is required',
            'content.required'    => 'Content is required',
            'title.unique'      => 'The title has already been taken. Try another title.',
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        return Alert::error(' Error Tambah Data ', ' Silahkan Periksa Kembali');
    }

}
```

and last this is the blade

```
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="TagNews" class="form-label"><b>Tags</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tags" value="{{ $arrTags }}" >
    @if ($errors->has('tags'))
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('tags') }}</span>
    @endif
  </div>
```

the error says "Call to a member function tag() on int", Does anyone have an example updating tag using package rtconner/laravel-tagging? if you have please take it on this post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `updateNews` method you're calling `update` and setting that as `$model`.

From the docs:

> The update method returns the number of affected rows.

So you're then calling `->tag($model)` on an int, rather than a model.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I found this discussion
https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/issues/101

so, maybe kind of like this

```
public function updateNews($id, $data)
{
    $tags = explode(',', $data['tags']);
    $model = Model::find($id);
    $model->retag($tags);
    Model::where('id', $id)->update($data);
    return $model;
}
```

notice: also make sure the configuration

```
// Auto-delete unused tags from the 'tags' database table (when they are used zero times)
'delete_unused_tags' => false,
```

in config/tagging.php is set to false

You can also read other usage examples
https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/blob/master/docs/usage-examples.md